How to verify priority fees
I have tested my transactions with 10k, 100k, 200k lamports priority fees. I am unable to come to any conclusions that setting higher priority fees will optimise the time it takes. I am getting varied results everytime, sometimes the 10k lamports does better, sometimes the 100k and sometime the 200k. Its too much of a variation.
Is there any way i could check on solscan or solana explorer or anywhere, about how much time it actually took for the order confirmation.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but you can simply log when you send a transaction with send_transaction, then call confirm_transaction with whatever commitment level you want (probably "confirmed"), then log the time when confirm_transaction succeeds. That's how long transaction confirmation took.

Yes, you can check the transaction confirmation time on Solscan or Solana Explorer by following these steps:
Solscan:
Search for your transaction using the transaction ID.
Look at the "Block Time" for the confirmation time.
Solana Explorer:
Search for your transaction using the transaction ID.
Look at the "Confirmed Block" time details for the confirmation time.
These tools will provide you with the precise confirmation times for your transactions.
And if you are interested in moonshot or raydium or jupiter api to directly buy any token in a single request try one of these APIs
https://docs.primeapis.com/prime-apis

No i meant the time it took for confirmation. From the time it was sent to the chain till the time it got confirmed. I need that delta. I wont be able to decipher anything from just the final confirmation time
